# Fill null value by previous value and group by Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, null

I have an table and I want to fill the null value with previous value order by date but there have an group too
For example:
Table X:

| Date | Group | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | null |
| 2/1/2023 | A | Kevin |
| 3/1/2023 | A | null |
| 4/1/2023 | A | Tom |
| 5/1/2023 | A | null |
| 6/1/2023 | A | null |
| 1/1/2023 | B | Sara |
| 2/1/2023 | B | null |

So I want to group by Group column and fill the null value of value column, The group can be multi value and the date is unique per group. I want the result like this:

| Date | Group | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | null |
| 2/1/2023 | A | Kevin |
| 3/1/2023 | A | Kevin |
| 4/1/2023 | A | Tom |
| 5/1/2023 | A | Tom |
| 6/1/2023 | A | Tom |
| 1/1/2023 | B | Sara |
| 2/1/2023 | B | Sara |

How can I do it in postgresql ? Please help me

I have tried and I realy don't know how to do it. I just a newbie too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have more than one NULL values consecutively, `LAG` function won't help you much. A generalized solution would use:

- the `COUNT` window function to generate a partitioning of one non-null value and consecutive null values
- the `MAX` window functions to reassign NULL values.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN value_ IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER(
               PARTITION BY Group_ 
               ORDER     BY Date_
           ) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Date_, Group_, MAX(value_) OVER(PARTITION BY group_, rn) AS value_
FROM cte
ORDER BY group_, Date_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bFDziHkDiixmVh6bCTbJmn/2).

Answer (score 0):

If the input data is always in this form, we can use `GREATEST` and `LAG`:

```
SELECT
xdate, 
xgroup,
GREATEST(xvalue, LAG(xvalue) OVER()) AS xvalue
FROM X
ORDER BY xgroup, xdate;
```

Try out here with your sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U3pBbt-s)

`GREATEST` fetches the highest of two (or more) values which is `NOT NULL`, `LAG` selects the value from the previous row.

If this is not sufficient in your scenario due to possible more complex input data, please edit your question to add further cases which should be covered.

In this answer, the columns were renamed by adding a x because the original names are SQL keywords and should be avoided if possible.